# Как из Django передать переменную в Javascript

Tags: javascript, django

Хочется:
views.py:

```
request.session['id'] = id
```

JS:

```
var id = sessionStore.getItem('id');
```

Но JS говорит id=null

Добавил в шаблон html:

```
<script>var id={{ id }}</script>
```

JS её видит... но как-то не по фэншую такой способ... Как сделать правильно?

Comment: Так это разные вещи.

Comment: кэп очевидность.  ответ очень помог

Comment: Ты пишешь в сессию бека. Пытаешься получать его из сессии фронта. Ещё и удивляешься, почему **JS говорит id=null**

Comment: Ты прям супермен-очевидность )) Вопрос стоит не "почему не работает", а "Как сделать чтоб работало?"

Answer (score 3):

Вы пытаетесь использовать COOKIE. Что как правило ведёт к нарушениям безопасности. По это причине Django не даёт простого способа передавать данные в "печеньках", вместо этого обменивается с браузером только 32-х битным хэшем сессии а всё остальное решается в backend. Если что то нужно передать на "фронт" используйте контекст шаблона.

```
#Сохраняет в базу данных
request.session['id'] = id
#Берёт в свою очередь из браузера, по тому и не работает
var id = sessionStore.getItem('id');
```

НО. Если всё же так хочется что неможется, вот подсказка:

```
response = HttpResponse("F*ck your safety Django")
response.set_cookie('id', '123')
return response
```

Comment: Благодарствую! Мне как раз и надо единственным id'шником пулять туда. Так что, думаю, разработчики джанги простили бы меня :)